# Door bell with Wi-Fi camera

Tags: smart-home, surveillance-cameras, door-sensor

I'm looking for a door bell with a camera I would prefer something like 180° fish eye with 4k, but I guess there is nothing on the market so 160° with FullHD should work too. Should I mention that I want night vision too? ;)

I checked NEST Hello, the ring.com door bells and August Doorbell. They are almost perfect, but they all rely on the fact that the video signal cannot been stored locally without an cloud and expensive subscriptions.

Is there something which I may have missed?

Comment: For future readers: note that the larger the view angle with the same resolution, the fewer pixels per degree, hence lower detail in the image. That might be very much okay for a short range doorbell camera, but might render regular cameras quite useless for viewing at longer distances. (Like to recognize faces or read text.)

Comment: You can get cheek enough ESP32 with BT+WiFi + camera on AliExpress. E.g [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32968683765.html) The advantage, if you can code, is that your data do not go through someone else's server

Comment: @Mawg FYI: I bought the Doorbird bell and I am happy with it. The Doorbell does not require out of my view internet even if I am using it so for more comfort.

Comment: Just curios. How does't the doorbell's camera communicate with ... your hand phone?

Comment: I use their mobile app, but the Doorbell has SIP for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ordered now a [Doorbird D101S](https://www.doorbird.com/downloads/datasheet_d101s_en.pdf), [the API](https://www.doorbird.com/downloads/api_lan.pdf?rev=0.21) looks nice so far even if I was skeptic in the first place. I will play around with it and will report the results. I'm very interested in the callbacks can be used with so called "favorites" (check the API for details).

The *"[connect](https://www.doorbird.com/connect)"* options looks also very interesting so there are many options to integrate it into other systems.

Comment: Ah I almost forgot this Question: The Doorbell is great for my usage. The callbacks works well and I can do what I like. I can even view the picture from the web. Just the camera resolution is bad. Together with PoE I just need 4 wires to power and control the device.

Answer (score 2):

There are few models available in market with 180 degree capability including:

Sky Bell HD

Ring Video Doorbell

Vivint Doorbell Camera

But these are not having 4K quality on video. Please refer below site for more details:

http://mobilesiri.com/best-wireless-doorbell-camera/